# how can axios interceptor handler get access to vue component instance(this pointer)within whose created method is invoking axios.get?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Axios is a great library capable of doing ajax both in browser and in node environment. vuejs is a great framework used for component based web development. Normally, it is excellent for a vue comonent to use axios to launch ajax operation.
According to https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios , we can use following code to integrate vue and axios.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.prototype.$http.interceptors.request.use(function(request){
    // I want to access the vuecomponent instance here, how can i do that??
    console.log((this.$options._componentTag ? (this.$options._componentTag+ 
   ' of '+ (this.$parent.$options._componentTag? 
   this.$parent.$options._componentTag:'root')): 'root component')+ ' for 
   url: ' 
   +request.url+ ' body: '+JSON.stringify(request.body))
}
   return request
},function(error){ return Promise.reject(error)});
// normally, following code will be run within vue component created hook 
   method, this represent the vuecomponent, $http is axio
this.$http.get(api).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data)
})
```

and, also, i'd like to know in which vue component the ajax operation is being executed. So, i use the interceptors to address that problem.
Unfortunately, this pointer does not represent the vuecomponent, how can i implement that?

Comment: What exactly do you need that information for? Usually the api logic should be decoupled from the components and you would pass any data you gathered back in reactively via vuex.

Comment: @bodo, there are pretty much ajax request in a complex spa. I'd like to know which request is launched by which component in some cases.

Comment: That doesn’t really answer my question. Why do you need to have that information?

Comment: @bodo, i am not sure i exactly understand your question. As i mentioned, In debug mode,  i want to log out all the ajax request log covering: which url for what data ajax is launched against by which vue component. Previously, vue-resource work very well for that purpose, unfortunately, when siwtched to axios, it does not work any more. I am trying to figure out how to fix it

Comment: In that case you can probably use the callstack.

Comment: @bodo, can you give some more explaination on your idea about callstack?

Comment: you can use `console.trace()`, but if you need more advanced functionality there is probably a library out there for analyzing the callstack / stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use vue-axios library, but you can implement it by using vue mixin like sample below:

```
let httpMixin = {
  methods: {
    get: function (url) {
      // You can access `this` here
      // ...

      return this.$http.get(url)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins: [httpMixin],
  created: function () {
      // Use mixin methods instead $http
      this.get('/api/xyz').then(...)
  }
})
```

Just make it more reusable :')

Comment: yes, we can access `this` in that manner. My question is: can i access `this` vuecomponent in the 'myrequestcallback' anonymous function parameter in the  $http.interceptors.request.use(myrequestcallback)?

Comment: in fact, this workaround solution is quite near my requirement. I can change my code in this manner to log out which component is launching ajax against which url in the this.get('/api/xyz'). But i can not figure out how to do similar things to log out about the data in the ajax session for a specific url by specific vue component instance

Comment: Untested but i think you can pass anything you need to axios request from mixin (`$http.get(url, { component: this }`) for example), and then you can use information of component passed above in axios interceptor (ofcourse it included axios request session)

Comment: in interceptor: ```http.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log(request.component)
  return request
})```

Comment: great idea, i will give a try and let y updated if i can succeed. thanks

Comment: @Huang, it really works, i accept your idea to implement my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The package/plugin `vue-axios` is not my favorite. If you google `vue axios` it’s the first result. And I think that’s the main reason of it's popularity.
But this is an alternative. We just override the `Vue.prototype.$http` and `Vue.prototype.axios` using [the original Axios Library](https://flaviocopes.com/axios/)

You don't need to use `vue-axios`:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
Vue.prototype.axios = axios;
```

As we can see it takes the same amount of lines to write the whole functionality ourselves as it takes to configure the plugin.

```js
const api = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';
let childComp;

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
Vue.prototype.axios = axios;

childComp = {
  template: '<div><p>{{msg}}</p></div>',
  created() {
    console.log('child created');
    this.$options._componentTag = 'tag-1';
    this.$parent.$options._componentTag = 'parent-tag-1';
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('child mounted');
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello Vue',
    }
  },
}

Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    console.log('parent created');
  }
})


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(childComp),
  methods: {
    load: function() {
      app.$http.interceptors.request.use(function(request) {
          //console.log(app.$options.components);
          // I want to access the vuecomponent instance here, how can i do that??
          let name = app.$options._componentTag;
          console.log(name);
          let parentName = app.$root.$options._componentTag;
          console.log('C');
          console.log(
            (name ? (name + ' of ' + (parentName ? parentName : 'root')) :
              'root component') + ' for url: ' + request.url + ' body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
          return request;
        },
        function(error) {
          return Promise.reject(error)
        });
      // normally, following code will be run within vue component created hook 
      // method, this represent the vuecomponent, $http is axios
      app.$http.get(api).then((response) => {
        //console.log(response.data);
      });
    },
  },
});

app.load();

var Ctor = Vue.extend({
  name: 'cool-stuff'
});
var vm = new Ctor();
// console.log(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your snippet, but it does not catch my point. All the $options._componentTag stuff is properties of the vuecomponent instance which has fired the axios.get ajax request. I am trying to figure out how to access the vuecomponent instance from within the axios.interceptors.request

Comment: You mean you want to get access to the internal components of the Vue Class?

Comment: yes. I want to access the vue class instance in the interceptors, i know there should be some trick for passing context(this pointer of js) to the callback functions, or some wrappers similar to jquery $('button').click(callbackhandler). But no clear clue

Comment: Mhm the interceptors are part of the `axios`, not part of the `vue` instance. Let me think how to do that.

Comment: @kidsit, Please explain me what you want to do, or achieve, probably there is another alternative an this path is just not the best way. U said you want to pass an instance to an API method like `click`, but u can use `this` the question is where?

Comment: what i want is: in the axios interceptors , i want to have access of vue-component instance from which the axios ajax is launched. My question is, how to pass the vue-component instance to the interceptor handler callbacks. the jquery stuff is something i demonstrated,maybe,can give some inspirations to solve this problem